# chrome not show site menu but IE show it please help me

Tags: google-chrome

hi my chorme browser not show the content of drop down menu
for example:uast.ac.ir
my IE show this site fully but chrome not show
please help me

Comment: Not too sure what's the problem with this question. It's pretty clear to me that the menu of the given website doesn't show the right contents, while it does in IE.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can do about it, it's just bad programming. A lot of companies still only work with Microsoft products and don't test their code to see if it actually works on other browsers. Microsoft is a company that deviates from standards quite regularly, so it's normal that IE specific code doesn't always work in other browsers.

You could contact the admin for the site and ask to revise the code, or use the tools they dictate you to use, i.e. running IE.

This problem was huge in Western countries as well, especially dealing with banks and government sites, but since the rise of Chrome and Firefox (and lots of users who complain), they're working on it now. It does cost a lot for a company to make these changes, so they probably need some incentive to do it :)